# How get all widgets of certain type?

Tags: gwt

I have an **AbsolutePanel** and different widgets (Buttons, Images, Labels, e.t.c.) on it.  Is it possible to get collection or array or whatever of all widgets of certain type, for example - Image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go :

We can use `iterator.`

```
Iterator<Widget> arrayOfWidgets = abslPanel.iterator();
while (arrayOfWidgets.hasNext()){
  Widget ch = arrayOfWidgets .next();
  if (ch instanceof Button) {
  //Do something (in your case make an arraylist of your objects)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup this is it, Why didn't the question isn't closed?

Comment: @Piccaza Questions are not closed for getting answers here; they can get future answers, still

Comment: This method doesnt find all widgets in the panel, just the widgets added to the panel but not those added to its children panels

Comment: @FFire already mentioned that "widgets on it".So his requirement will fulfill.Thanks for the missed point.

Answer (score 2):

If you add gwtquery to your project it is really easy:

```
List<Image> allImages = $("*", myPanel).widgets(Image.class);
```

And even you could use sophisticated css selectors to perform a finer discrimination:

```
List<MyWidget> allMyWidgets = $("*:nth-child(even)", myPanel).widgets(MyWidget.class);
```

Comment: +1, but in my opinion its overkill use an external library for one function only.

Comment: Yep you are right, but actually gquery is really light-weight and offers a lot of useful shortcuts to the java world which makes your live really easy, so this could be for you the very first reason to use gquery ;-) . In fact I dont start any gwt project without including a couple of libraries: gin and gquery. It's much easier to write a couple of lines in my pom.xml and my ui.xml files than write some blocks of code like iterators.