# in GWT, How to loop Gui Widget inside a panel?

Tags: gwt, loops, user-interface, panel

Let say, I got a VerticalPanel that have some widgets (label, button, ...) that were added into it. How can i loop that VerticalPanel & access the widgets in it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can use `iterator`,As i explained in the question [How get all widgets of certain type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15307883/how-get-all-widgets-of-certain-type/15308009#15308009).

```
Iterator<Widget> widgets= vpanel.iterator();
```

Point to remember:

- This method only gives the widgets added to the panel.
- You have to iterate over child panels also(if its contains).

Or otherwise pick @Manolo's answer from same thread,If you are using GWT third party library GQuery.